# Android PagedList not showing data from local if offline?

Tags: java, android, android-paging, pagedlist

I have done various ways, but to no avail

DataSource

```
public class NetReqDataSourceFactory extends DataSource.Factory {

    private static final String TAG = NetReqDataSourceFactory.class.getSimpleName();
    private MutableLiveData<NetReqPageKeyedDataSource> networkStatus;
    private NetReqPageKeyedDataSource moviesPageKeyedDataSource;
    public NetReqDataSourceFactory(Context context, String status) {
        this.networkStatus = new MutableLiveData<>();
        moviesPageKeyedDataSource = new NetReqPageKeyedDataSource(context, status);
    }


    @Override
    public DataSource create() {
        networkStatus.postValue(moviesPageKeyedDataSource);
        return moviesPageKeyedDataSource;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<NetReqPageKeyedDataSource> getNetworkStatus() {
        return networkStatus;
    }

    public ReplaySubject<ReqDataList> getData() {
        return moviesPageKeyedDataSource.getData();
    }

}
```

PageKeyedDataSource

```
public class NetReqPageKeyedDataSource extends PageKeyedDataSource<String, ReqDataList> {

    private static final String TAG = NetReqPageKeyedDataSource.class.getSimpleName();
    private final MutableLiveData networkState;
    private final ReplaySubject<ReqDataList> moviesObservable;
    private final ConnectionServer connectionServer;
    private final String status;
    private final MasterRepository repository;

    NetReqPageKeyedDataSource(Context context, String status) {
        networkState = new MutableLiveData();
        connectionServer = new ConnectionServer(Util.getApiWithAuth(context, (new ArrayList<ReqDataList>()).getClass(), new ReqJsonDeserializer()));
        moviesObservable = ReplaySubject.create();
        this.status = status;
        this.repository = MasterRepository.getInstance(context);
    }

    public MutableLiveData getNetworkState() {
        return networkState;
    }

    public ReplaySubject<ReqDataList> getData() {
        return moviesObservable;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<String> params, @NonNull final LoadInitialCallback<String, ReqDataList> callback) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Loading Initial Rang, Count " + params.requestedLoadSize);
        Log.i(TAG, "Loading Initial, Status " + status);
        networkState.postValue(NetworkState.FIRST_LOADING);
        connectionServer.getReqByPage(1, status).enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<ReqDataList>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<ReqDataList>> call, Response<ArrayList<ReqDataList>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    callback.onResult(response.body(), Integer.toString(1), Integer.toString(2));
                    networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED);
                    if (response.body().size() > 0) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            response.body().forEach(moviesObservable::onNext);
                        } else {
                            for (ReqDataList data : response.body()) {
                                moviesObservable.onNext(data);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        networkState.postValue(new NetworkState(NetworkState.Status.FIRST_FAILED, "Nothing here yet, pull to refresh & try again"));
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("API CALL", response.message());
                    networkState.postValue(new NetworkState(NetworkState.Status.FIRST_FAILED, response.message()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<ReqDataList>> call, Throwable t) {
                String errorMessage;
                if (t.getMessage() == null) {
                    errorMessage = "unknown error";
                } else {
                    errorMessage = t.getMessage();
                }
                networkState.postValue(new NetworkState(NetworkState.Status.FIRST_FAILED, errorMessage));
                callback.onResult(new ArrayList<>(), Integer.toString(1), Integer.toString(2));
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void loadAfter(@NonNull LoadParams<String> params, final @NonNull LoadCallback<String, ReqDataList> callback) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Loading page " + params.key );
        networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING);
        final AtomicInteger page = new AtomicInteger(0);
        try {
            page.set(Integer.parseInt(params.key));
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Call<ArrayList<ReqDataList>> callBack = connectionServer.getReqByPage(page.get(), status);
        callBack.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<ReqDataList>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<ReqDataList>> call, Response<ArrayList<ReqDataList>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    callback.onResult(response.body(), Integer.toString(page.get() + 1));
                    networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        response.body().forEach(moviesObservable::onNext);
                    } else {
                        for (ReqDataList data : response.body()) {
                            moviesObservable.onNext(data);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    networkState.postValue(new NetworkState(NetworkState.Status.FAILED, response.message()));
                    Log.e("API CALL", response.message());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<ReqDataList>> call, Throwable t) {
                String errorMessage;
                if (t.getMessage() == null) {
                    errorMessage = "unknown error";
                } else {
                    errorMessage = t.getMessage();
                }
                networkState.postValue(new NetworkState(NetworkState.Status.FAILED, errorMessage));
                callback.onResult(new ArrayList<>(), Integer.toString(page.get()));
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void loadBefore(@NonNull LoadParams<String> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<String, ReqDataList> callback) {

    }
}
```

PagedList.Config

```
public class ReqNetwork {

    final private static String TAG = ReqNetwork.class.getSimpleName();
    final private LiveData<PagedList<ReqDataList>> moviesPaged;
    final private LiveData<NetworkState> networkState;

    public ReqNetwork(NetReqDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory, PagedList.BoundaryCallback<ReqDataList> boundaryCallback) {
        PagedList.Config pagedListConfig = (new PagedList.Config.Builder())
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(20)
                .setPageSize(10)
                .build();
        
        networkState = Transformations.switchMap(
                dataSourceFactory.getNetworkStatus(),
                (Function<NetReqPageKeyedDataSource, LiveData<NetworkState>>) NetReqPageKeyedDataSource::getNetworkState
        );
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        LivePagedListBuilder livePagedListBuilder = new LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, pagedListConfig);
        moviesPaged = livePagedListBuilder.
                setFetchExecutor(executor).
                setBoundaryCallback(boundaryCallback).
                build();

    }

    public LiveData<PagedList<ReqDataList>> getPagedMovies() {
        return moviesPaged;
    }

    public LiveData<NetworkState> getNetworkState() {
        return networkState;
    }

}
```

LocalDataSource

```
public class DbReqDataSourceFactory extends DataSource.Factory {

    private static final String TAG = DbReqDataSourceFactory.class.getSimpleName();
    private DbReqPageKeyedDataSource moviesPageKeyedDataSource;
    
    public DbReqDataSourceFactory(ReqDataDao dao, String filterStatus) {
        moviesPageKeyedDataSource = new DbReqPageKeyedDataSource(dao, filterStatus);
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource create() {
        return moviesPageKeyedDataSource;
    }
}
```

LocalPageKeyedDataSource

```
public class DbReqPageKeyedDataSource extends PageKeyedDataSource<String, ReqDataList> {

    public static final String TAG = DbReqPageKeyedDataSource.class.getSimpleName();
    private final ReqDataDao dataDao;
    private String filterStatus;
    public DbReqPageKeyedDataSource(ReqDataDao dao, String status) {
        dataDao = dao;
        filterStatus = status;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<String> params, @NonNull final LoadInitialCallback<String, ReqDataList> callback) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Loading Initial Rang, Count " + params.requestedLoadSize);
        Log.w(TAG, "loadInitial: " + filterStatus);
        List<ReqDataList> data = null;
        if (filterStatus == null) {
            data = dataDao.getListAll();
        } else {
            data = dataDao.getListAllByStatus(filterStatus);
        }
        if(data.size() != 0) {
            callback.onResult(data, "0", "1");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void loadAfter(@NonNull LoadParams<String> params, final @NonNull LoadCallback<String, ReqDataList> callback) {
    }

    @Override
    public void loadBefore(@NonNull LoadParams<String> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<String, ReqDataList> callback) {
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public LiveData<PagedList<ReqDataList>> getDataReqPage(Context context, String status){
        initReqPageDao(status);
        NetReqDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new NetReqDataSourceFactory(context, status);
        network = new ReqNetwork(dataSourceFactory, reqBoundaryCallback);
        reqLiveDataMerger = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        reqLiveDataMerger.addSource(network.getPagedMovies(), value -> {
            reqLiveDataMerger.setValue(value);
            Log.d(TAG, value.toString());
        });
        dataSourceFactory.getData().
                observeOn(Schedulers.io()).
                subscribe(item -> {
                    ReqData reqData = new ReqData();
                    reqData.req_sid = item.req_sid;
                    reqData.req_uid = item.req_uid;
                    reqData.req_total = item.req_total;
                    reqData.req_pemda = item.req_pemda;
                    reqData.req_lon = item.req_lon;
                    reqData.req_lat = item.req_lat;
                    reqData.req_address = item.req_address;
                    reqData.req_remark = item.req_remark;
                    reqData.address_id = item.address_id;
                    reqData.post_by = item.post_by;
                    reqData.post_date = item.post_date;
                    reqData.update_by = item.update_by;
                    reqData.update_date = item.update_date;
                    reqData.post_status = 1;
                    database.dataReqDao().insert(reqData);
                });
        return reqLiveDataMerger;
    }

    public void initReqPageDao(String status) {
        PagedList.Config pagedListConfig = (new PagedList.Config.Builder()).setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(Integer.MAX_VALUE).setPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE).build();
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        DbReqDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DbReqDataSourceFactory(database.dataReqDao(), status);
        LivePagedListBuilder livePagedListBuilder = new LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, pagedListConfig);
        reqPaged = livePagedListBuilder.setFetchExecutor(executor).build();
    }

    private PagedList.BoundaryCallback<ReqDataList> reqBoundaryCallback = new PagedList.BoundaryCallback<ReqDataList>() {
        @Override
        public void onZeroItemsLoaded() {
            super.onZeroItemsLoaded();
            reqLiveDataMerger.addSource(getReqData(), value -> {
                reqLiveDataMerger.setValue(value);
                reqLiveDataMerger.removeSource(getReqData());
            });
        }
    };

    public LiveData<PagedList<ReqDataList>> getReqData() {
        return reqPaged;
    }
```

ViewModel

```
    public LiveData<PagedList<ReqDataList>> getReqDataPaged(String status) {
        return getRepository().getDataReqPage(getContext(), status);
    }

    public LiveData<NetworkState> getNetworkState() {
        return getRepository().getNetworkState();
    }
```

Did you guys find my fault?

I load data using a Fragment inside the ViewPager

```
public class ReqListFragment extends BaseFragment<FragmentReqListBinding, ReqListViewModel> implements ReqListViewModel.Navigator {

    @Inject
    ConnectionServer server;
    @Inject
    MasterRepository repository;
    
    private FragmentReqListBinding binding;
    private ReqListViewModel viewModel;
    private String status;
    private boolean hasLoaded = false;
    
    @Override
    public int getBindingVariable() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.fragment_req_list;
    }

    @Override
    public ReqListViewModel getViewModel() {
        return viewModel;
    }

    public ReqListFragment newInstance(String status) {
        ReqListFragment fragment = new ReqListFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.STATUS, status);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
        binding = getViewDataBinding();
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new ReqListViewModel.ModelFactory(getBaseActivity(), server, repository)).get(ReqListViewModel.class);
        viewModel.setNavigator(this);
        status = getArguments().getString(Constants.STATUS);
        viewModel.filterStatus.postValue(status);
        if (status.equals(Constants.ALL)) {
            loadData(status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        binding.swipe.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), getResources().getColor(R.color.colorApprovedBg));
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        binding.swipe.setOnRefreshListener(()->loadData(status));
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(getView() != null && isVisibleToUser && !hasLoaded && !status.equals(Constants.ALL)) {
            loadData(status);
        }
    }

    private void loadData(String status) {
        binding.shimmerViewContainer.startShimmer();
        binding.shimmerViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final ReqListAdapter pageListAdapter = new ReqListAdapter(viewModel);
        viewModel.getReqDataPaged(status).observe(this, pageListAdapter::submitList);
        viewModel.getNetworkState().observe(this, networkState -> {
            pageListAdapter.setNetworkState(networkState);
            binding.setState(networkState);
        });
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(pageListAdapter);
        hasLoaded = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(String item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseActivity(), ReqViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.SID, item);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

In other conditions I succeed if I move the code `initReqPageDao` to the RoomDatabase class,

but i am confused about sending status for filter
Thank you all for your help, I hope I find the error and a solution